# MAMP database upload problem

Tags: database

I completely removed Acquia Dev Desktop & XAMPP and installed MAMP.

Plain vanilla Drupal 8 that I downloaded which is works. Now I want to import the database dump created by ADD, but keep getting an error message saying the file is too big. I believe the problem centers around php.ini. I can find no php.ini in the WAMP folder. I found php.ini-development & php.ini-production. I increased the parameters in both files relating to maximum file size upload, but they had no effect. I then copied php.ini-development & renamed it php.ini. I restarted the server, but it had no effect. Got any ideas as to how to fix this problem? i want to uploaded my new drupal website to this url https://www.kvtech.ae please help me to fix this problem.

Parameters changed -
max_execution_time = 30 to 1200

Changed post_max_size=8M to 128M
max_execution_time = 60 to 90000
upload_max_filesize=2M to 128M

Versions -

MAMP 3.2.0

Apache 2.2.27
Nginx 1.7.5
MySQL 5.5.41
PHP 5.3.23 & 5.4.1 & PHP 5.4.40 & 5.4.45 & 5.5.0 & 5.5.24 & 5.5.29 & 5.6.0 & 5.6.8 & 5.6.13 & 7.0.0
OpenSSL 1.0.2e
APC 3.1.13
APCu 4.0.4 & 4.0.7
eAccelerator 1.0
XCache 3.0.4 & 3.1.0
OPCache 7.0.4
Python 2.7.6
mod_wsgi 3.4.0
Perl 5.16.1
mod_perl 2.0.8
phpMyAdmin 4.2.7
SQLiteManager 1.2.4
phpLiteAdmin 1.9.4.1
Freetype 2.4.10
curl 7.36.0
libpng 1.5.18
ImageMagick 6.8.9-1
Imagick 3.1.2
gd 2.1.0
zlib 1.2.7
libxml2 2.9.1
gettext 0.18.1.1
iconv 1.14
mcrypt 2.5.8

Comment: FYI - The drupal Admin->Reports->Status page will have a link next to the PhP version that will show you a lot of info about PhP.. including the location of the current PhP.ini.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my preferred way of importing large databases.

I log in with mysql command line:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -uroot -proot
```

Then I create the database:

```
drop database mysite_local;
create database mysite_local;
use mysite_local;
```

Then to import the large database command by command use:

```
source ~/Downloads/mysite_local.sql
```

Then exit the mysql client:

```
exit;
```

You can also set up your drush to jump right into your database.  Since you'll be using the MAMP mysql instead the default on, you'll want to set up a symlink so that you can type mysql instead of the path to MAMP's mysql:

```
ln -s /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql /usr/local/bin/mysql
```

To get the terminal to recognize MAMP's php, you can add the correct
   php to your path variable in your bash profile.  For example:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.1/bin
```

To refresh the terminal so it uses the new path, type:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

At this point go to the site directory, for example, /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/web/sites/mysitefolder/ and
   type:

```
drush sql-cli
```

If you've set things up properly, you should be able to jump right into your database.

Or if you have a zipped file, you could do this to import the database:

```
gunzip ~/Downloads/dump-file.sql.gz | drush sqlc
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to import this via phpMyAdmin and that the file is an standard DB dump.

I would recommend either doing this via drush or the mysql command line.  E.g.:

```
drush @mysite sql-cli < \backup\my-dump.sql
```

Note:  drush @mysite status should show db schema and user name.

or

```
mysql -u user -p d8-database-schema-name < \backup\my-dump.sql
```

Another alternative would be to use the [MySQL Workbench Tool](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/).  Excellent GUI tool that runs on any OS and can even access databases via SSH.  Set up a connection to your DB, then load the dump as a script.  Make sure your target database schema is selected as default.